# Problem with returning values in toString method in java

Tags: java

I tried to return int values a,b, and c in my toString method, but it says "; expected" although there is a ";". I don't understand what is wrong. I have tried something like "APLine.getA()" and "getA()", but they all didn't work. Please help me. I feel so sad.

```
public class APLine
{
 private int a;
 private int b;
 private int c;
 private int x;
 private int y;

public APLine()
{
 a = 0;
 b = 0;
 c = 0;
 x = 0;
 y = 0;
} 

 public APLine(int A, int B, int C)
{
 a = A;
 b = B;
 c = C;
}

 public void setA(int A)
{
 a = A;
}
 public void setB(int B)
{
 b = B;
}
 public void setC(int C)
{
 c = C;
}

public int getA()
{
 if(a != 0)
 {
 return a;
 }
}

public int getB()
{
 if(b != 0)
 {
 return b;
 }
}

public int getC()
{
 return c;
}

public double getSlope()
{
 return (double)(-a)/b;
}

public boolean isOnLine(int x, int y)
{
 if(a*x + b*y + c == 0)
 {
   return true;
 }
  else
 {
  return false;
 }
}

public String toString()
{
 return ""a,b,c;
}

}
```

This is the main method.

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
APLine myLine = new APLine(5, 4, -17);


System.out.println("The slope is: "+ myLine.getSlope());
System.out.println("Is (5, 2) on the the line? "+ myLine.isOnLine(5,2));
System.out.println("Is (1, 4) on the the line? "+ myLine.isOnLine(1,4));

myLine = new APLine(-25, 40, 30);


System.out.println("The slope is: "+ myLine.getSlope());
System.out.println("Is (5, -2) on the the line? "+ myLine.isOnLine(5,-2));
System.out.println("Is (6, 3) on the the line? "+ myLine.isOnLine(6,3));
  }
}
```

This is what the compiler shows.

```
APLine.java:78: error: ';' expected
 return ""a,b,c;
          ^
APLine.java:78: error: ';' expected
 return ""a,b,c;
           ^
APLine.java:78: error: not a statement
 return ""a,b,c;
            ^
APLine.java:78: error: ';' expected
 return ""a,b,c;
             ^
APLine.java:78: error: not a statement
 return ""a,b,c;
              ^
5 errors
```

Comment: Try `"" + a + b + c;`. However this will just return something like `234`. So maybe `return "a = " + a + "\nb = "+ b + "\nc = " + c;` would be more like what you want

Comment: what are you trying in `toString()` method?

Comment: You can also try using `String.join` _static_ method. An example usage is: `return String.join(", ", a, b, c);`.

Comment: `String.join()` will not work @prasad

Comment: @prasad_ `a` `b` and `c` are `int`s, there is no `join` version for them.

Comment: Here is the corrected version: `return String.join(", ", String.valueOf(a), String.valueOf(b));`

Comment: How does `public int getA()
{
 if(a != 0)
 {
 return a;
 }
}` even compile?  No return values in all cases

Comment: I suggest that you use an IDE such as Eclipse.  It will quickly highlight for you your syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public String toString(){return ""a,b,c;}
```

to

```
public String toString(){return String.format("%s,%s,%s", a,b,c);}
```

Your expression is not valid.